# EF6 can I update model/table after lambda querying?

Tags: entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, lambda

I am lambda querying models (I make projection with other classes-GameBankVM, GameCouponBankVM) and at the end, I would like to loop throuh query result and update the model field. But I am getting The entity or complex type 'EPINMiddleWareAPI.Models.GameBankVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Here is my sample code:

```
 var gameBankResult = await (context.GameBanks.Where(g => g.productCode == initiate.productCode)
                .Take(initiate.quantity)
                .Select(g => new GameBankVM
                {
                    quantity = g.quantity,
                    currency = g.currency,
                    initiationResultCode = g.initiationResultCode,
                    productCode = g.productCode,
                    productDescription = g.productDescription,
                    referenceId = g.referenceId,
                    responseDateTime = g.responseDateTime,
                    unitPrice = g.unitPrice,
                    totalPrice = g.totalPrice,
                    coupons = g.coupons.Select(c => new GameCouponBankVM
                    {
                        Pin = c.Pin,
                        Serial = c.Serial,
                        expiryDate = c.expiryDate
                    }).ToList() 
                })).ToListAsync(); 

            if (gameBankResult.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in gameBankResult)
                {
                    item.referenceId = initiate.referenceId;
                    context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }


                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok(gameBankResult);
            }
```

How can I update referenceId on my GameBank model/table?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, your data won't be updated because your query is returning a List of GameBankVM and not a List of GameBank, now technically speaking, you are breaking SRP, you should either update your data or query your data not both in the same method, you may want to refactor your method like this :

1.- Create a private method for data update, in this case, you query directly GameBank iterate thru list entries, make your changes and save them to the database, this same method can return List of GameBank to avoid another database roundtrip.

2.- In the controller after you call your new method, you can run the transformation query to convert List of GameBank to List of GameBankVM and return it to the view.

There are many other ways to do this, I'm just recommending this as a less impact way to make your controller work. But if you are willing to make things better, you can create a business layer where you resolve all your business rules, or you can use patterns like CQS or CQRS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I used GameBankVM and GameCouponBankVM for query projection. All I want to do is, query database and if there are results, update them.

Comment: Precisely, I understand you need it for query projection, the case is you are not going to have tracking in query projections without the entity in the projection, look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Your query is returning back the VM entities which are not being tracked by EF.

Comment: With your guidance, I figured out how to accomplish query & update. I first query and update entity then make a projection.